# Knowing it should be "Tag Manager" and not "Tags Manager", is it too bad to still name it "Tags Manager"?

Tags: grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

Ok, so now that thanks to some of you I know the correct way to name a tool like this would be effectible "Tag Manager" and not "Tags Manager" due to "Tag" acts as an adjective in these cases, my (new) question is: **How much of incorrect does it sound from a native English POV if I finally decide to name it "Tags Manager"?**

The reasoning for this is I've realized I don't have any control in the way the tool is going to be alphabetically ordered in the list and "Tags Manager" simply gave me the desired ordering, which for this case is important... So if it's not the more correct way but turns out it's still kind of *passable* (due to, for what I've read by the provided links, there seems to be a degree of ambiguity around the issue anyway) I may end up declining in favor of the plural form, unless it sound too bad to your ears (remember I'm Spanish) or there is simply no way it's near to be grammatically *acceptable* of course.

Well, I hope it makes sense to reopen the question this way and thanks for any further advice!

**EDIT:** Well I've finally opted for the singular form no matter what. After some thinking, I believe I'll be able to solve gracefully enough the alphabetical order issue in some way or another (I hope ) and, as I commented bellow, I don't think I could live seeing it all the time incorrectly written knowing what I know now... Thank you to all the people that helped! And very specially to @eltomito

Comment: It would be good if you could mention those "similar managing tools". And maybe find out what the difference would imply by looking for information (online) first.

Comment: Are you managing tags as a set or properties of individual tags?

Comment: @Joachim I'm not sure I can say one... I'd swear I have seen ir equally for similar functionality tools. The point here is I'm not sure if the "s" adds any value at all to the name in this case (somehow emphasizing the tool is designed to manage a bung of different tags) or it's basically superfluos info since it goes without saying, since this "tags" are clearly sub-elements in project terms. I mean... (MORE)

Comment: @Joachim (CONT'D) I can see why this plural/singular explicit distinction by that "s" would make all the sense in case I were talking about e.g. a "Projects Manager" or "Project Manager", because the first one would be clearly designed manage several projects and the second one would be intended as a tool to manage the project you are in, bur in the other case I'm not sure if the difference is so clear or if it's so necessary to make the distinction.
 
I hope it makes sense...

Comment: @Robusto  At first I thought that would have an easy answer, but now that I'm thinking on it I'm not so sure... I mean, the manager helps to manage these tags along the project (applying them, deleting'em from layers, etc.) but also act over individual tags by allowing you change its settings and so... So in this case I think both definitions would be correct, if I understood the question well...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It, and very specially the link there to the other question in [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/229234/image-directory-or-images-directory-pluralizing-of-attributive-nouns/229726#229726), has definitely been of great help, thanks!

Comment: You may be unaware of our sister site SE English Language Learners, which is appropriate for this common question from native speakers of Romance languages where adjectives agree with nouns in number. English isn’t like that and anyone tries to provide a logical explanation is kidding themselves and you. An explanation in terms of the evolution of the language is another thing, and more what this site is about, but I don’t think that is what concerns you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "tag manager". "Tag" is a noun but in the phrase "tag manager", it functions as an adjective. And when you use a noun as an adjective, you use it in the singular. That's why cats get "cat food" even though it's food for a lot of cats and you can use a "mosquito net" to fend off more than one mosquito.

Of course, there are exceptions such as people eating "people food" instead of "man food" (e.g., when kept as pets by aliens) and driving "sports cars" instead of "sport cars" but they're just exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for answering! It throws quite light around the issue the fact of seeing it from that "adjective" POV. I still have a little doubt, though... What do you think about the other "Projects Manager" VS "Project Manager" case I commented just above? Do you think in that case it'd be justified enough to use the plural to ensure it's clear one is talking about two very different purpose tools? I think so because it's like in the case of "Projects Manager" _Projects_ would pass to act as a sustantive and, therefore, changes all the meaning, isn't? But I just wanted to make sure...

Comment: I still think it should be Project Manager. If you want to make it clear that it manages multiple projects, call it something like Multiproject Manager.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! It's very good to can ear so clear opinions about a subject because thanks to it using the plural form is starting to sound weird even in those cases where I thought it could be justified... So I really hope I can solve the alphabetical ordering issue I commented after editing the question, otherwise I don't think I'll find myself confortable seeing "Tags Manager" all the time knowing what I know now...